# Making an endpoint for file validation and storing into a db?

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, storage, file-handling

I am using `ASP.NET Web API` and I don't know if this is more of a javascript/frontend related issues but :

1. I want to send a file to an endpoint and **only** validate it using the
   `(HTML) file input onchange event.`
2. I have a separate Upload button in the frontend which will be disabled by default and will be enabled depending on the response of the validation.
3. If I get an **OK** response from the validation then the button will be enabled and if clicked, it will parse and store the data of the file in the database.

**I don't want to store the data in db unless the user 'clicks' the upload button.**

Do I need to have two separate endpoints for validation and storage(parse & store in db)
or is it possible to handle with a single function?

Comment: What kind of validation you want to do? It should be possible in single method. The front-end and API communicate via Ajax, and all this disable thing can be done by JavaScript or jQuery

Comment: I am validating a csv file btw. So, the `file input onchange event` can do the validation as well as the storing (if validated) directly. But I want the click in the frontend to handle the storing of data. Can you please suggest any resource related to this problem? @Maytham